# Facebook login doesn't redirect into own app in Xcode 5 but its working in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed iOS application with facebook login integration and i have used Facebook SDK for login, i workout the sample application its working in Xcode 4 but i used the same Supporting files in Xcode 5. When i click the facebook login button its ask E-mail & password after getting E-mail & Password it directly goes to Facebook application it's not Redirecting into My own application. I need to Redirect in to my own application after getting the E-mail & Password how to solve this.

Comment: check this [facebook login link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/) . may be you are missing the URL Schema . check in your plist setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve that issue follow these steps.
[image]
Select your Project Target -> Info -> URL Types "Expand URL Types" -> Identifier - > give your bundle identifier last word (example) if your bundle identifier is "com.facebook.myAPP" then you need to give "myAPP" in identifier Field

In URL Schemes -> give your fb e.g."fb1267389406"